# Scala - Obtain DAG with stages and tasks without execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am searching for a way to obtain the DAG of Scala Spark application using RDD, including the stages and tasks.

I have tried `rdd.toDebugString` but it only shows the RDD lineage, not the DAG i'm looking for.

I know there is the web UI which displays the DAG, but I want to extract the DAG from the code, in a similar fashion like the `explain` function does for the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

The following points:

- `rdd.toDebugString` is for RDDs prior to execution ONLY.
- *Execution DAG* is something that you can observe at run-time for both RDD and Dataframes via *Spark Web UI*. See new release: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/web-ui.html
- *Prior to execution* you can ran an `.explain` for Dataframes.
- From a good source:

> Spark SQL EXPLAIN operator provide detailed plan information about sql
>   statement without actually running it. You can use the Spark SQL 
>   EXPLAIN operator to display the actual execution plan that Spark
>   execution engine will generates and uses while executing any query.
>   You can use this execution plan to optimize your queries.

A simple example for the Dataframe:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row     
val dfsFilename = "/FileStore/tables/sample_text.txt"
val readFileDF = spark.sparkContext.textFile(dfsFilename)  
val wordsDF = readFileDF.flatMap(_.split(" ")).toDF
val wcounts3 = wordsDF.filter(r => (r(0) != "Humpty") || (r(0) != "Dumpty"))
                      .groupBy("Value") // Note the value
                      .count().explain()
```

You tag the statement appropriately, but not on a show(), for a Dataframe/Dataset.

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[Value#4], functions=[finalmerge_count(merge count#14L) AS count(1)#8L])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(Value#4, 200), [id=#61]
   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[Value#4], functions=[partial_count(1) AS count#14L])
      +- *(1) Filter <function1>.apply
         +- *(1) SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true, false) AS value#4]
            +- Scan[obj#3]
```

- You can see some restrictions / subtleties here [Spark 2.x - How to generate simple Explain/Execution Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575490/spark-2-x-how-to-generate-simple-explain-execution-plan).
- In Spark 3.x I am not so sure it can work the same as there is run-time evaluation on what to do. I.e. *Adaptive execution of Spark SQL*. here is the link: https://medium.com/cloudzone/apache-spark-3-0-review-what-the-spark-is-all-about-998844e12b3c

Your specific question: Not possible and possibly not entirely valid as there is little optimization to consider.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking at RDD instead of Dataframe. In addition, I want to obtain the DAG not from the web UI, but from the code. I will clarify that in my question.

Comment: @MiaTran could you figure out some way to visualize the DAG from code ?

Comment: @thebluephantom how we can do some query optimization from the physical plan. could you give me some examples?

Comment: @AkashPatel  that is a new question, but https://medium.com/datalex/sparks-logical-and-physical-plans-when-why-how-and-beyond-8cd1947b605a   you have a selected plan but adapative can differ. you can rewrite your query to influence the optimzer of course

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `explain` function, you can also view the webUI when executing your application - if you run locally, it should be on `http://localhost:4040/` (as described in the documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html). It provides a list of jobs, a visualization of the DAG for each job, configurations, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using RDD so the ```explain``` function can't be used. I was also looking at the web UI, but I'm looking for a way to get the DAG from the code instead, in a similar fashion like the ```explain``` function

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible, except for toDebugString. That said, RDDs are not so optimizable, so I am not sure the point is valid.

Comment: Probably you can run a .toDF() at the end and that may give the answer you need.